# Can list of IDs(string) be passed to a delete method for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, collections

I have a list of Ids that need to be deleted. I'm getting my collection from the database and passing it a resource. From which I want to iterate through the collection and delete a list of Ids being passed.

Before I was deleting records with a filter but I no longer need to search for Id as I am now passing a list of Ids.

```
public Task<DataRetentionOperationResult> 
DeleteIdentifiedDataAsync(List<String> Ids, String Resource, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var collection = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(Resource);

        foreach (var id in Ids)
        {                
            collection.DeleteManyAsync<BsonDocument>(id, cancellationToken);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I expect for the documents associated with the Ids passed to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove multiple documents you can build a filtering condition based on `Ids` using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) operator. Please remember about `awaiting` Async functions,

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In(f => f["_id"], Ids);
await collection.DeleteManyAsync(filter);
```